# How to pass more than one variable from PHP into R?

Tags: php, r

When i was learn about integrating PHP and R, i got from this [source](http://www.r-bloggers.com/integrating-php-and-r/)

that for passing variable from php into R have to use

```
 exec("Rscript my_rscript.R $N");
```

But it only could passing one variable into R. How if i want to pass more than one variable into R? 
Any help? Thankyou in advanced :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$N1="any command";
$N2="any command";

exec("Rscript my_rscript.R  $N1 $N2");
```

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply. I already tried, but im still feeling confused for access that two variable inside R. Could you give me an example to use $N1 & $N2 inside R? Thankyou

Comment: $N1=1 
$N2= 2 
This R script will have 2 arguments 1 and 2

Comment: Yeah it's not working. I don't know which parts could be wrong... For more info, Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34349467/php-variable-in-r