# Php Variable in R

Tags: php, r

I tried to pass the php variables to be used in RScript. But i confused to catch that php variables in R

Here's my php Code

```
<?php
    if(isset($que) && isset($cekque))
    {
        $N1 = $que;
        $N2 = $cekque;

        exec("Rscript QC.R $N1 $N2");
        $nocache = rand();
        echo("<img src='temp2.png?$nocache'/>");
    }
?>
```

Here's My Rscript

```
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
N1 <- args[1] 
N2 <- args[2]
data0<-dbGetQuery(con,N1)
jml <-dbGetQuery(con,N2)
rataan<-mean(as.numeric(data0$round))
sd<-sd(as.numeric(data0$round))
ewma(data0,jml$count,rataan,sd,0.2,3,plot=TRUE)
dev.copy(png,'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\AMQC\\Code\\CodeElbert\\temp.png',width = 716, height = 439)
dev.off()
```

But The error still show up.

[image]

And the image would be shown like this

[image]

Any help? I thought my Rscript was wrong. Thankyou

Comment: Why do you think it fails? Any error message?

Comment: I've already completed the question @Pascal . :D

Comment: I asked before, lolilol